# How do I clear this warning, and what does it mean?

Tags: sequence, networkx, graph-theory

The code runs and produces the desired graph. However, my console shows the following message:

FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
  pos = np.row_stack((pos[x] for x in node_list))

My question is what does this mean? How should I change the code to fix this warning?

This is my first time asking about code so if I made a mistake please let me know.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([0, 1, 2, 3])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2)])
G.adjacency()
pos = nx.planar_layout(G)

# nodes
options = {"node_size": 500, "alpha": 0.8}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[0, 1, 2, 3], node_color="r", **options)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G,
    pos,
    edgelist=[(0, 1), (1, 2)],
    width=8,
    alpha=0.5,
    edge_color="r",
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What vesion of networkx are you using? Seems to run fine for me

Comment: @yatu version 2.4

Comment: I don't believe this is about your version of networkx, rather about your version of numpy.  I think networkx is using a numpy command, but numpy is warning that in the future that command will no longer work.  I personally would just ignore it.  It will presumably be updated in the next version of networkx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what does this mean?

The expression `(pos[x] for x in node_list)` yields an object of `class 'generator'`; an expression `[pos[x] for x in node_list]` would yield an object of `class 'list'`.

> How should I change the code to fix this warning?

You would have to change the parentheses to e. g. brackets in the shown expression in the library code, but, as Joel noted, this will probably be done by the library maintainers.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!